# 'docker logs' throws error when trying to access an exited container

Tags: logging, docker

I want to run Consul from the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/) using

```
docker run -d consul -P
```

`-P` should map all EXPOSED ports from the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-consul/blob/9a59dc1a87adc164b72ac67bc9e4364a3fc4138d/0.6/Dockerfile) to the host. Running the command without `-P` works just fine, `docker ps` displays this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                  NAMES
bc23fb8b61a6        consul              "docker-entrypoint.sh"   3 seconds ago       Up 1 seconds        8300-8302/tcp, 8400/tcp, 8500/tcp, 8301-8302/udp, 8600/tcp, 8600/udp   jovial_booth
```

When using `-P` the container exits immediately. When I run

```
docker logs bc23fb8b61a6
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid flags before the subcommand. If these flags are for
the subcommand, please put them after the subcommand.

usage: consul [--version] [--help] <command> [<args>]

Available commands are:
[…]
```

I also tried to map `/var/log` from the container to a local directory, unfortunately it remains empty.

Any ideas what is going wrong and how I can access the container's logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `-P` argument (which belongs to `docker run`) before the `consul` command:

```
docker run -d -P consul
```

Otherwise it is interpreted by Consul and you get a syntax error message for the `consul` command.

Comment: Stupid me, figured that out myself later but forgot to check back here. Thank you anyway for your answer :-).